# MS Teams : How to define closeHandler for Task module when it opens via deeplink?

Tags: microsoft-teams

In our application, we used to open a task module through a deep link. When I click on the cross (X) button from such a task module, the background keeps the loading spinner there. I need to handle the event for this cross (X) button clicked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please share your deep link and could you please check your console errors to find out why the task module is not getting closed? Please refer to [Task module deep link syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/invoking-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax) for further understanding. There is no callback method available for task-module. So its not possible to handle the event for cross button click.

Comment: Thanks, Meghana. The task module is closing but I do not have a close handler for the same when I open the task module through deep link. But as you said there is no such way to in your answer. so sorted for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Task module deep link syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/invoking-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax) for your understanding. There is no callback method available for task-module. So its not possible to handle the event for cross button click.